# Building a loop in R to write all rows into separate files, with one row per file

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, statistics

Here, I'm looking at the file mtcars in R.  This is one loop that can be used to write columns into 11 separate files, since there are 11 columns in the dataset.

```
for(i in (1:length(mtcars[1, ])))
write.table(mtcars[i], file=paste("mtcars", as.character(i), ".txt", 
sep=""), row.names=FALSE, sep="\t");
```

I'm just curious, how would you do this if you were to change it into writing all columns into separate files?  Right now, I know one modification to make would be that we set the first line length parameter to mtcars[,1] instead, but I'm curious what you can substitute the i with? Are there any other substitutions that need to be made in other parts of the code?

Edit: missing quote

Comment: I think it would be extremely helpful if you can tell me which parts of the code refer to organizing in terms of columns and talk about how I can change them into that of rows.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence *I'm just curious, how would you do this if you were to change it into writing all columns into separate files?*.  Isn't that what you were already doing?

Comment: I'm building a loop in R to write all rows into separate files, with one row per file.  What I have above is the loop that does it for columns.  I'm asking about how I can use similar logic and modify that code for rows.

Answer (score 3):

Your code already writes each column into a separate file. Do you want to replicate the whole table 11 times? In that case, just `write.table(mtcars, ...`

Edit: Try this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)
write.table(mtcars[i,], file=paste("matchers", as.character(i), ".txt", 
sep=""), row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

Or without a for loop:

```
sapply(mtcars, 1:nrow(mtcars), function(i) 
  write.table(mtcars[i,], 
              file=paste0("matchers", i, ".txt"),
              row.names=FALSE, sep="\t") )
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(index = 1:n() )
  rowwise %>%
  do(write.table(., 
                 file=paste0("matchers", .$index, ".txt"),
                 row.names=FALSE, sep="\t") )
```

Comment: I meant to ask for how I can do this for rows, because I'm honestly stuck there.